# Printing Array to file only prints first element

Tags: c, arrays, struct, printf

I'm currently trying to use a struct "test", to print an array of 10 random things the user inputs. The program compiles, and runs, however after I enter the final 10th item, the .txt file only contains the first element I've entered.I've tried moving the area of which the fprintf function is called, but my attempt at that was to no avail. Any input on this would be much appreciated.

**Continues to only print the first element (i.e what I type first)**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ncurses.h>
//EDIT NEW CODE UPDATED, BUT IT STILL ONLY PRINTS THE FIRST ELEMENT\\
typedef struct test
{

    char test[10];
}test;

int main(void)
{
  initscr();
  cbreak();
  noecho();

  testFunction();
}

int testFunction()
{
    int i;
    test inputString[10];

    FILE *f = fopen("file.txt", "w");
    for(i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
        mvprintw(50,50,"Please enter a 10 things");
        getstr(inputString[i].test);
        fprintf(f, "%s\n", inputString[i].test);

    }
       fclose(f);


}
```

Comment: why don't use check error codes and return values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're closing your file inside the loop, and not opening it again.

Move the fclose() call to outside your loop.

By the way, you don't need the while loop.

Comment: It still only prints the first element.

Comment: You put the fclose outside the loop, but you still didn't remove the fclose from inside.